# Proving program correctness under all possible cases

Tags: design, programming-practices, generic-programming

> There are techniques of proving program correctness under all possible
> cases, but that is a more advanced topic, for a later subject in your
> curriculum.

I always had this doubt:

1. Is it possible to know all possible defects in a program before I write a single line of code? (i.e., How to detect a bug during the designing and planning stage itself.)
2. If yes, what are the strategies used by the professionals?

I've observed that if I am able to detect all possible logical flaws in designing and planning stage itself then overall development time is reduced.
Currently to detect all possible flaws, I often run the program using all cases in my mind or on paper.
As a senior engineer What techniques do you use?

Comment: It's not always impossible, but for most software which actually makes money, the concept of "correctness" and notion of "all possible cases" are often fluid, subjective ideas that depend a great deal on human opinion, human behaviour and assumptions about the future, to the point where most software is usually deeply rooted in unknowable factors where it is logically impossible to define what the term correctness even means.   As such, It's exceptionally rare for all possible use cases to be truly knowable or able to be fully defined in absolute, mathematically provable terms.

Comment: As a new learner, I can't add much, but having such a mindset that it will not arise can be a trial. The moment you started and say that it will have this error is unpredictable.

Comment: Hey @Ben Cottrell, if that's the case then what are the techniques/strategies do you use so that overall development time is reduced.

Comment: While it is often impossible to prove general correctness properties, one specialized strategy is quite common: static type systems serve as an automated proof of some properties, assuming that the type system is “sound” (many are not). A basic property would be that a variable `int x` will only contain integers, never strings. More interesting properties ensure that a value will either be one case or another, or that a value can only exist after some initialization succeeded (compare RAII in C++). Rust was designed so that the type checker can prove the absence of certain bugs that plague C.

Answer (score 9):

Ensuring correctness of a computation mathematically is quite possible, just enormously expensive. Basically, you have to set down the requirements in a formal semantic system that is as rigid as a programming language itself. This involves an astonishing amount of work (contrary to popular opinion, requirements engineering is the hardest part of SE by far, much harder than coding).

You can do it if you have extremely important and slow-changing requirements and a client with very deep pockets - the standard example in the literature is the codebase of the systems that ran the Space Shuttle, which is considered the most correct large codebase in history. For almost all other projects, doing this is simply not cost-effective.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you need to include the operating system in your correctness analysis. If `malloc` isn't formally correct, any program that calls `malloc` isn't correct either.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I guess that extends all the way down, in that the hardware must be (and must under all circumstances remain) correct. For the space shuttle, the hardware reliability side was also taken seriously.

Comment: @Kilian Foth If that's the case, then what are the techniques/strategies do you use so that overall development time is reduced? I've observed that since most projects have a time constraint, so most developers are forced to write low quality code.

Comment: @Dan you dont *prove* correctness, you just *gather evidence* of correctness, most of the time

Comment: @Caleth Please read this especially[Design](https://py.mit.edu/fall22/readings/design) read 2.2 last two points a) Does your plan make use of all the inputs? b) Does it produce all the proper outputs? c) Thinking back to your understanding of the problem, are there any interesting "edge cases" that should be considered? Does your plan account for those?  I was referring to those points How do you achieve those tasks?

Comment: This answer is talking about proving correctness about a program after it was written, whilst the question asks for the opposite - proving correctness before a program was written.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to know what a "bug" is. In some projects this might be rigorously defined, in other projects it might be "I do not like the color". And opinions *will* differ about what is a bug or not, or what the "correct" behavior is, so this is much more complicated that it might first appear.

I would argue all projects are in some sense iterative. There *will* be cycles of planning, implementing and evaluation, so trying to find *all* issues before doing *any* implementation is doomed to failure. You should still *try* to find bugs and other problems as early as possible, but some issues will only be apparent when doing implementation. And you should be alert to "bugs" in *all* stages of development.

For user-facing applications, this might involve showing a prototype in front of a user, or user representative, as fast as possible. That should hopefully help with finding issues in the requirements.

Trying to predict problems often comes down to experience. The better you know the problem domain the less unexpected issues you will have, and the more the risk is reduced.

But once you have started writing a formal problem description (i.e. writing code) you can start using *tools* to help you. The first line of defense is usually the compiler, this will eliminate some classes of bugs. Then you have various types of analyzers that can help detect some types of bugs, but will have some false positives.

Then there is Automated testing. This can tell you if some specific input give correct output, but that require you to specify what the expected output is. This might range from unit testing where you test some small piece of code, to full scale simulations.

The sketching out all possible paths thru a program by hand is only possible for fairly small programs. It is a good approach to write "modules" that are small enough that this approach is applicable to the module in isolation.

But this still runs the risk [leaky abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), where the abstractions you rely on does not quite match reality. As an example, you might treat a `Double` as 'real number', but this abstraction can fail, for example if you get a NaN as input. And when programs get large it becomes very difficult to predict how all modules will interact in all circumstances, even if you understand the "normal case" well enough. See [Mars climate orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter) crash where different modules used different units, or [Ariane 88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_flight_V88) where a module where used outside of its original design parameters.

So my experience is that "proving correctness" by just analyzing code is of limited value. In practice you need testing, automated or not. The amount of testing is highly dependent on context, the testing regime for aviation software would be completely different from that of a game.

This is in principle not different from designing physical products. You should use the available tools to model behavior and help to predict failures. But you still need to test the thing to check that you have not missed something.

Answer (score 1):

It seems noone here answered your literal question:

> Is it possible to know all possible defects in a program before I **write** a single line of code

For this question, the answer is trivial: it is clearly **no**. When there is no code, you cannot even tell if your program has a syntactical error, since there is nothing to evaluate.

The answer by KilianFoth has implicitly replaced the word "write" by "run" in your question (maybe because he assumed that's what you really wanted to know). If he got you right, follow [his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/442078).

However, from what you wrote in the comments, I guess the question you really wanted to ask is

> Is it possible to know all possible defects in a **program design** before writing a single line of code

Here, the answer is still "no"  - except for some very special scenarios. The reason is, high level software design artifacts, which are on a higher level of abstraction than code, are usually too informal to allow a rigorous proof of their defect-freeness. Typical design artifacts contain natural language, which cannot be rigidly tested like code. It is not even always obvious what a defect is. And even "design languages" like UML have often no strict semantics, which makes sometimes the line between correctness and incorrectness blurry.

Moreoever, when one puts also requirements under the umbrella of design and planning artifacts, it is should be clear you cannot decide if a requirement is "correct" or "incorrect", since requirements themselves are the benchmark for what is correct or incorrect.

However, that does not mean that all of this is in vain. Design artifacts and requirements can be analysed and reviewed by humans. Here systematic proofreading and walkthroughs by yourself or a second pairs of eyes is typically used for find inconsistencies or gaps in the design, or contradictions between requirements and design.

None of these techniques, however, can eliminate all potential issues, they can only lower the count. The ultimate test for a high-level design is when you start to implement parts of it in code, test that code and compare how well it maps to the requirements you want to achieve. That is why the most effective design validation technique is to implement parts in executable code, ideally in small iterative cycles, and not in a "Big-Design-Upfront".

Comment: What are the techniques/strategies do you use so that overall development time is reduced? I've observed that since most projects have a time constraint, so most developers are forced to write low quality code.

Comment: I meant was that when I do a design I would like to know whether that design has any type of logical flaws.

Comment: Detecting logical flaws in design stage itself will reduce development time.

Comment: Define "design stage". What I call "design stage" usually involves coding. Do you include "requirements gathering" in your definition of design stage? Use case descriptions? Data flow analysis? Prototyping? Or do you believe "design stage" is what happens when you draw some UML diagrams?

Comment: Please read this especially, [link](https://py.mit.edu/fall22/readings/design) read 2.2 last two points a) Does your plan make use of all the inputs? b)Does it produce all the proper outputs?
c)Thinking back to your understanding of the problem, are there any interesting "edge cases" that should be considered? Does your plan account for those?

Comment: Yes! what you describe here is correct everything.

Comment: @Dan: see my edit. I guess your question's wording is pretty misleading, please check if I got you right,